# Is there any pattern behind the naming conventions of PostgreSQL Table-Level Locks?

Tags: postgresql, naming-convention, documentation

I know that PostgreSQL has 8 level of table locks which are, from least restrictive to most:

1. ACCESS SHARE
2. ROW SHARE
3. ROW EXCLUSIVE
4. SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE
5. SHARE
6. SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE
7. EXCLUSIVE
8. ACCESS EXCLUSIVE

However, I can't really determine any pattern or convention to these names.  There are literally 5 words total: ACCESS, SHARE, ROW, EXCLUSIVE, and UPDATE, which are grouped together, seemingly at random, for all 8 levels.  I find myself preferring to refer to them as just L1 through L8 rather than their actual names.

Are these names just the result of historical conventions that evolved organically in a way which doesn't really have any meaning besides "look at the docs and see what level each is?"

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) "*the names of the lock modes are historical. To some extent the names reflect the typical usage of each lock mode*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/explicit-locking.html) calls such names "historical"

> the names of the lock modes are historical.

Such names were used in the very [first version](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/3f7fbf85dc5b42dfd33c803efe6c90533773576a#diff-5a4b5dde4abfc865a832b1439fc025d95e4e3b223378a021c20cebe508af4a92R26) of the MVCC implementation. Over the past 24 years, there has not been a sufficiently substantiated proposal to somehow change the names.

Probably it is not possible to find why such names were originally choosen, but looking at the compatibility notes to `lock table`:

> Except for ACCESS SHARE, ACCESS EXCLUSIVE, and SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock modes, the PostgreSQL lock modes and the LOCK TABLE syntax are compatible with those present in Oracle.

I have a guess: the names were chosen according to those in Oracle.

PS: it's not a really good idea to refer to locking levels by numbers (although they are just integer constants) because it is possible to add a blocking level "in the middle", as happened in the past with [`SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/4fe42dfbc3bafa0ea615239d716a6b37d67da253#diff-5a4b5dde4abfc865a832b1439fc025d95e4e3b223378a021c20cebe508af4a92)